# insert missing user records from a union in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have three tables (`users`, `students`, and `staff`). All three tables share three common attributes (`emplid`, `first_name`, and `last_name`). I want to be able to do a union on `students` and `staff` like so:

```
SELECT emplid, first_name, last_name 
FROM students 
UNION 
SELECT emplid, first_name, last_name 
FROM staff
```

I then want to take that resulting query and insert any users into the `users` table that are considered to be "new" (in the unioned results but not in the query table).

How would I accomplish this using SQL (specifically PostgreSQL)?

```
INSERT INTO users (...)?
```

Comment: The question is: why do you have three identical tables in the first place? You should only have a single table and another table defining the "role" of that person (student, staff, user)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well this example is GREATLY over-simplified. The tables contain lots of other information that makes them unique. These are the only three columns they share between them

Comment: @kyledecot Still sounds like a relational modelling problem. Your `students` and `staff` tables should both have a foreign key on `emp_id` referring to `users(emp_id)`.

Comment: @CraigRinger Unfortunately I don't have control over either of those tables at my company so I have to work with what I'm given. Unfortunate but that's the way big companies go sometimes :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` would probably simplest here:

```
INSERT INTO users (emplid, first_name, last_name)
SELECT sub.emplid, sub.first_name, sub.last_name
FROM (
   SELECT emplid, first_name, last_name
   FROM   students
   UNION
   SELECT emplid, first_name, last_name
   FROM   staff
   ) sub
LEFT JOIN users u2 USING (emplid, first_name, last_name)
WHERE u2.emplid IS NULL;
```

You can join `LEFT JOIN` to another instance of the same `users` table *before* the `UPDATE`.

And I hope you are doing this to clean up all the redundant storage? (Probably no use saving all those columns in multiple tables.)

Alternatively, you could eliminate existing rows in `users` from each leg of the `UNION` query *before* the `UNION`. More verbose, but might be cheaper with complete index support, because eliminating duplicates with `UNION` gets cheaper.

Overview over related techniques:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: ... and remember to `LOCK TABLE staff, students, users IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` first.